# Knockout.JS mapping to observable vs. observableArray

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0, ko.observablearray

I can't figure out why my ko.mapping is working fine when I'm bringing back an array (using the 'foreach' binding), but when it's a single object (using the 'with' binding) it doesn't work at all.  I don't get any errors, but I also don't get any results:

```
function EventViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.events = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.singleEvent = ko.observable({});

    self.getEvents = function () {
        self.events.removeAll();
        $.ajax("/api/Event/", {
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (allData) {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(allData, null, self.events);
            }
        });
    }    
    self.getSingleEvent = function () {
        self.events.removeAll();
        $.ajax("/api/Event/?guid=435a666b-7913-417f-a474-dfb33d74c2ec", {
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (allData) {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(allData, null, self.singleEvent);
            }
        });
    }

    self.getEvents();
    self.getSingleEvent();
};
window.vm = new EventViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

I can shove the result from getSingleEvent() into an array and use 'foreach' again like this:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS([allData], null, self.singleEvent);
```

and make singleEvent an observableArray, which does work, but it seems like a cheat to me.

The JSON from getEvents() looks like this:

```
[{"EventId":4,"Year":2013,"StartDate":"2013-08-28T00:00:00","EndDate":"2013-09-02T00:00:00","EventGuid":"435a666b-7913-417f-a474-dfb33d74c2ec"},{"EventId":5,"Year":2013,"StartDate":"2013-06-07T00:00:00","EndDate":"2013-06-09T00:00:00","EventGuid":"615014ba-15cd-4371-8d43-04d66eb558a2"}]
```

and the JSON from getSingleEvent() looks like this:

```
{"EventId":4,"Year":2013,"StartDate":"2013-08-28T00:00:00","EndDate":"2013-09-02T00:00:00","EventGuid":"435a666b-7913-417f-a474-dfb33d74c2ec"}
```

Comment: What does the JSON data look like that is coming back from your api?  That would determine the resulting Javascript object type.

Comment: Just edited the original post with JSON samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure that ko.mapping does not make objects observable. Instead it makes each of the properties of an object observable. On the other hand, nothing is stopping you from just doing `self.singleEvent(allData)` to set the observable.

Comment: This led me down the right path; `self.singleEvent(ko.mapping.fromJS(allData));` in getSingleEvent()'s success did the trick!  Thanks!